# React <Typeahead> set default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set default value in typeahead,

Here is my code::https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sound-pzse0?file=/src/App.js

```
   <FormGroup>
                          <label
                            className="form-control-label"
                            htmlFor="input-email"
                          >
                            Account
                          </label>
                          <Typeahead
      id="input-account"
      onChange={setSelected}
      options={lookuplist}
      placeholder="Choose a Account..."
      selected={selected}
      filterBy={['name']}
      labelKey={lookuplist => `${lookuplist.name} (${lookuplist.id})`}
      defaultValue={editcontacts.phone}
    />
                        </FormGroup>
```

The defaultValue is not rendering in typeahead,

Comment: Should work like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-voice-shg6z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: defaultInputValue is the correct property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the [api](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/API.md#typeahead), you can use the `defaultInputValue` prop if you want to set a default value for the `Typeahead`.

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-jackson-elrzt?file=/src/App.js)